# C++ passing a mutex to a member variable in the constructor

Tags: c++, class, mutex, member

I have a problem with passing a mutex to my class. I have a class named `Test` with the a member variable called `m_Mutex`. In the constructor I want to transfer the parameter mutex to `m_Mutex`.

My class:

```
#include <mutex>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(mutex &mtx) :
        m_Mutex(mtx)
    {
    }

private:
    mutex m_Mutex;
};
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
   mutex mutex1;
   Test t(mutex1);
   return 0;
}
```

Error:

> function "std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)" (declared at line 88
>   of "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\mutex")
>   cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it that I am able to pass the mutex?

Comment: Sounds like XY problem, why do you need to pass mutex in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short terms: you can't. Mutexes are neither copyable nor movable. And they aren't for a good reason. If however you want to achieve this nontheless, you might pass it by using a unique_ptr:

```
class A {
   unique_ptr<mutex> mutexPtr;

   A(unique_ptr<mutex> ptr) : mutexPtr(std::move(ptr)) { }
};

A a{std::make_unique<mutex>()};
```

Note that if you want to share the mutex between different objects, you should use shared_ptr or weak_ptr instead.

Comment: Without knowing why OP needs to pass it this answer could be not applicable.

Comment: In general terms, it is no good idea anyways to have movable/copyable mutexes. I supposed the OP has a good reason and knows what he is doing. That's why I wrote that mutex is constructed like it is for a good reason.

Comment: Good reason would be that OP needs to share that mutex, otherwise it is better just have it inside class. If that the case your answer is wrong.

Comment: That's true, but the modification is minimal: use shared_ptr then. I will adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: But your answer should use `shared_ptr` I cannot see any reason to use `unique_ptr` here.

Comment: The OP might just want to use the mutex and when he is done using it, he wants to transfer the ownership to the object for further applications. Totally valid scenario.

Comment: Sounds very artificial and I bet it is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Jodocus why would you want to transfer ownership of a mutex?  You'd just have 2 mutex's if they're protecting different things; and if they're not protecting different things then they should be wrapped together so that you never need to transfer ownership

Comment: I agree with others @Jodocus you answer is semantically good but is really making something very complex for a small thing.

Comment: @ UKMonkey: To make sure it stays alive. When passing a plain reference, the whole object gets invalid when the mutex expires and there is no way to find out. Of course you can also use weak_ptr, so you don't have to pass the ownership, but still can check whether the reference is still valid or not.

Comment: @ Pierrot: I assume the object will be used in a multithreaded manner. If a reference to mutex was used that was created at a different thread than that one where the object is used, one thread may invalidate another thread's object. This is a very undesirable behaviour! If you see an easier (but safe!) solution, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 3):

> In the constructor I want to transfer the parameter mutex to `m_Mutex`

Unfortunately you can't. `std::mutex` is not copyable and not moveable.  One thing you can do if you want to declare the mutex somewhere else is to store a reference to the mutex like

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(mutex &mtx) :
        m_Mutex(mtx)
    {
    }

private:
    mutex& m_Mutex;
};
```

Comment: This is potentionally dangerous as there is no way inside Test to find out whether the reference to the mutex is still valid. If you want to share the ownership, a shared_ptr (or weak_ptr) should be used instead.

Comment: Can I lock and unlock the mutex with this code in other functions from the class Test? With `m_Mutex.lock()` and `m_Mutex.unlock()`?

Comment: @User987123 Yes, but the class it self becomes not copyable and not moveable.  Jodocus solution of using a smart pointer will allow you to move /maybe copy it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <mutex>

class Test
{
public:
Test(std::mutex &mtx) :         
    m_Mutex(mtx)
{
}

private:
std::mutex &m_Mutex;           // note the "&"
};


int main()
{
 std::mutex mutex1;
 Test t(mutex1);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should really explain why the member variable needs to be a reference to be a good answer (see NathanOlivers answer as an example).

Answer (score 2):

Just keep mutex inside your class (probably as static member) and if you need to  allow other classes to use it provide access:

```
class Test 
{
public:
    Test() {}
    std::mutex &mux() { return m_Mutex; }
private:
    mutex m_Mutex;
};
```

or even this:

```
class Test {
public:
    using lock_t = std::scoped_lock<std::mutex>;
    Test() {}

    lock_t lock() { return lock_t( m_Mutex ); }
private:
    mutex m_Mutex;
};
```

usage:

```
Test t;
{
    auto lock = t.lock();
    // object t is locked till end of the block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a reference

Your mutex must be the same for all instances of your class, if it's not the case the lock you do in one instance of your class won't be active for the other one.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test(mutex &mtx) :
        m_Mutex(mtx)
    {
            m_Mutex.lock();
            i++;
            cout << "Test " <<i<<endl;
            m_Mutex.unlock();
    }

private:
    mutex& m_Mutex;
    static int i;
};

int Test::i =0;

int main()
{
   mutex mutex1;
   Test t1(mutex1);
   Test t2(mutex1);
   return 0;
}
```

see it live : https://wandbox.org/permlink/6YJFG3MI7m7RbfoL

Comment: why do you want a const mutex?  how do you plan to lock it?

Comment: `std::mutex::lock()` is not a const method.

Comment: sorry I wanted to point out that it would be logical to make it const but it won't work, but I figured out it will be promoting wrong code which is not good.